# MSBuild Build Artefacts references

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

The ask is simple. When msbuild generates the dll/exe for a project, does it store any reference to the NuGet packages in the generated artefacts?

I have an application that refers to, for example, Newtonsoft.Json. I manage the version of the NuGet package to be used using Directory.Build.props, where I define a variable for storing the NuGet package version number.
This variable in turn is used in the csproj file to point to the correct NuGet package.

Now, say for instance, my project refers to Newtonsoft.Json version 13.2.0 whereas on my server Newtonsoft.Json version 13.3.0 is present. The Build succeeds, and I deploy my dll to the server.

Will the dll fail to recognize the present Newtonsoft dll? Or if it does recognize, will the code behave unexpectedly?

Insights?
Thanks,
Yogesh H

Answer (score 0):

When MSBuild generates the DLL or EXE for a project, it embeds all the necessary dependencies into the output file, including the NuGet packages that are referenced by the project. Therefore, the generated artifact contains all the necessary code and metadata required for the application to run (including the references to NuGet packages).

In your scenario, if your project refers to Newtonsoft.Json version 13.2.0 and you deploy the generated DLL to a server where Newtonsoft.Json version 13.3.0 is present, the runtime should still be able to find and use the Newtonsoft.Json version 13.2.0 that is embedded in the DLL. However, if there are any breaking changes or critical bug fixes between version 13.2.0 and version 13.3.0, your code may not behave as expected.

Some sources for this:

- [Microsoft's documentation on MSBuild references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reference?view=vs-2022)
- [The NuGet documentation on how NuGet packages are restored and
  resolved during build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore)

Comment: Thank you for answering this @this. Do you have any references to any articles that I can read for further understanding?

Comment: I added some sources for further information to the answer